# ¿Qué error encuentran cuando agrego una llave foránea? en mi siguiente código de SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table Departamento(
    nroDepto varchar(4) primary key not null,
    nombreDepto varchar(15) not null,
    ciudad varchar(20) not null,
    director varchar(20) not null
)
go

create table Empleados (
    nDIEmp varchar(12) primary key not null,
    nomEmp varchar(40) not null,
    sexEmp char(1) not null check(sexEmp IN('M','F')),
    fecNac date not null,
    fecIncorporacion date not null,
    salEmp float not null,
    comis float not null,
    codSuc varchar(15) not null,
    jefeID varchar(12),
    cargoE varchar(15) not null,
    nroDepto  varchar(4) not null,

    constraint fk_Empl foreign key (jefeID) references Empleados,
    constraint fk_Dpto foreign key (nroDepto) references Departamento
)
go

alter table Departamento
add constraint fk_EmpDir foreign key (nroDepto) references Empleados(nDIEmp)
```

Msg 1753, Level 16, State 0, Line 29 La columna 'Empleados.nDIEmp' no tiene la misma longitud o escala que la columna de referencia 'Departamento.nroDepto' en la clave externa 'fk_EmpDir'. Las columnas que participan en una relación de claves externas deben estar definidas con la misma longitud y escala. Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 29 No se pudo crear la restricción o el índice. Vea los errores anteriores. Este error me sale.

Comment: Sería más simple si tu nos dices que error obtienes al ejecutar esto desde tu gestor de bases de datos

Comment: Msg 1753, Level 16, State 0, Line 29
La columna 'Empleados.nDIEmp' no tiene la misma longitud o escala que la columna de referencia 'Departamento.nroDepto' en la clave externa 'fk_EmpDir'. Las columnas que participan en una relación de claves externas deben estar definidas con la misma longitud y escala.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
No se pudo crear la restricción o el índice. Vea los errores anteriores. Este error me sale.

Comment: Toda esa información agregala editando tu pregunta, para que sea mejor recibida por la comunidad

Comment: Gracias, lo acabo de agregar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente tu error parte de que:

- Tu llave primaria en la tabla `Departamento` tiene una longitud de 4 para un tipo `VARCHAR`, pero posterior cuando tratas de hacer la unión con la tabla `Empleados` mediante su llave foránea declaras que `nDIEmp` sea si de tipo `VARCHAR` pero con una longitud de 12.

Lo anterior causa incompatibilidad y el mensaje de error que ves, entonces la solución es que tanto la llave primaria como la foránea sean:

- Del mismo tipo
- De la misma longitud

**Código**

Tabla `Departamentos`

```
create table Departamento(
    nroDepto varchar(12) primary key not null,
    nombreDepto varchar(15) not null,
    ciudad varchar(20) not null,
    director varchar(20) not null
)
```

Tabla `Empleados`

```
create table Empleados (
    nDIEmp varchar(12) primary key not null,
    nomEmp varchar(40) not null,
    sexEmp char(1) not null check(sexEmp IN('M','F')),
    fecNac date not null,
    fecIncorporacion date not null,
    salEmp float not null,
    comis float not null,
    codSuc varchar(15) not null,
    jefeID varchar(12),
    cargoE varchar(15) not null,
    nroDepto  varchar(12) not null,

    constraint fk_Empl foreign key (jefeID) references Empleados,
    constraint fk_Dpto foreign key (nroDepto) references Departamento
)
```

Final:

```
alter table Departamento
add constraint fk_EmpDir foreign key (nroDepto) references Empleados(nDIEmp)
```

**REFERENCIAS**

En el siguiente enlace puedes leer mas al respecto de la sintaxis al momento de crear llaves primeria sy foráneas

[SQL Server Docs. foreign keys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Gracias pudo compilar!

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer, pero me sale este mensaje, ¡Gracias por tu comentario! Los votos emitidos por quienes tienen menos de 15 de reputación se registran, pero no cambian la puntuación que se muestra públicamente.

Comment: @DavidTacuchi checa el enlace que te anexé te puede ser útil y servir de guía a futuro

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que estás tratando de relacionar dos columnas con diferentes longitudes. Departamento.nroDepto es un varchar de largo 4 y hace referencia a Empleados.nDIEmp que también es un varchar pero de largo 12.

O dejas ambos de largo variable o les das el mismo largo.